# Infalting the Layout showing not proper result

Tags: android, android-layout, android-inflate

I am inflating a layout in a Linear Layout.But at run time it is not showing up the proper layout .data is getting mixed up with each other.No proper spacing between the data.
this is how it is looking up 
[image: Image How it is coming up]

This is my **Activity Code**

```
void setApprovalDetailsData(){
        resultTrips = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.trip_list);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams mainTripDetailsLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams forUnderLine = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        forUnderLine.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        //mainTripDetailsLayout.setMargins(0, 40, 0, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
            TextView line = new TextView(this);
            line.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.shape_line);
            line.setLayoutParams(forUnderLine);
            if (i != 0) {
                resultTrips.addView(line);
            }

            LinearLayout tripdetailsdata = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.tripdetailsdata, null);
            resultTrips.addView(tripdetailsdata);
        }
        TextView dummy = new TextView(this);
        dummy.setLayoutParams(mainTripDetailsLayout);
        resultTrips.addView(dummy);
    }
```

Main **XML file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/top_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/back_btn"
            android:onClick="goBack"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="Self Travel Request Queues"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/headerList"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/options"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="39dp"
           android:background="@drawable/gray_bg123"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:weightSum="5">

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RequestedOn"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ApprovalID"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="TripDate"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="TripID"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="ApprovalStatus"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="6dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="hello"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerList">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/trip_list"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/top_bg" >


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**TripDetails XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainResultLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/request_date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="25 Sep 2013 | 09:45" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/approval_id"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="In30075042" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trip_date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="25 Sep 2013" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trip_id"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="FB30073KIFWB" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/approval_status"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Waiting" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The image link i have posted that is not showing data in proper way.Please help me to make it proper.Thanks

After @gaurav suggestion this is how it is showing up Still not proper

[image: Image After Gaurav Suggestion]

Comment: use `android:layout_weight` and `padding` for each textview.

Comment: i have already done that see in my XML

Comment: @Ketan so now what i have to please help me

Comment: @PoojaDubey if you have given weight to TextView inorizontal then its width will be set to 0...

Comment: @PiyushGupta i have already done that see in my XML

Comment: @PoojaDubey in Main.xml'

Comment: @PiyushGupta in the Linear Layout whose it is options or some other one

Comment: @PoojaDubey set layout Gravity center for all textViews

Comment: In the main xml i have done  android:layout_gravity="center"

Comment: @PiyushGupta still it is not showing up properly

Comment: you have to also set gravity:center for textviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this 
**tripdetailsdata.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainResultLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/request_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="25 Sep 2013 | 09:45" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/approval_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="In30075042" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trip_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="25 Sep 2013" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trip_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="FB30073KIFWB" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/approval_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Waiting" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in your **activity xml**

```
<LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/options"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="39dp"
           android:background="@drawable/gray_bg123"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:weightSum="5">
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to display a data table. Therefore I think you should use a TableLayout instead of a LinearLayout:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html